# Mock api stream output in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, nock

I am trying to mock external API output which comes as stream(chunk) in XML which I am parsing.
I am trying to write a unit test to mock API and send mocked data but it's not working with NOCK which I am using for API mocking.

When I run Test, I see 
*res.on('data', function(data_) {*
does not get executed.
If you would like to run, please create "a.txt" file with any XML content.

Any help is appreciated. Any other framework apart from NOCK is also welcome.

```
var request = require('superagent');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

var getMyData = function(callback) {
  parser.on('error', function(err) {
     console.log('Parser error', err);
     callback('Error Occurred!'+err);
  });

 var data = '';
  request    
    .get(`https://myapp.com`)    
    .end(function(err, res) {      
      if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 400) {        
        res.on('data', function(data_) {
          //console.log('--------------------------');
          data += data_.toString();
        });        
        var datainjson = '';
        res.on('end', function() {          
          parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {            
            if(!err){
              datainjson = JSON.stringify(result);
            }else{
              datainjson = 'Error Occurred!'+err;
            }
          });
          callback(err, datainjson);
        });
      }
  });
};
module.exports.getMyData = getMyData;


var should = require('chai').should();
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var nock = require('nock');
var fs = require('fs');
var getMyData = require('./index4').getMyData;

describe('test mock', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {        
    // Mock the TMDB configuration request response
    nock('https://myapp.com')
      .get('')
      .reply(200, function (req, res) {        
            var stream = fs.createReadStream('a.txt');
            stream.pipe(res);                
        });
  });

  it('should have data', function(done) {
    this.timeout(3000);
    getMyData(function(err, testdata) {
      var x = JSON.parse(testdata);      
      });
      done();
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: You should explain what "is not working" means. Maybe reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask helps you improving the question.

Comment: @Markus : res.on('data', function(data_) does not get executed. Due to which Timeout error come.

Comment: You should add this bits of information to the question. So people trying to help simply can read the question to have everything at hand.

Comment: I have updated details in question as suggested by Markus.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the stream from the nock reply callback:

```
nock('https://myapp.com')
  .get('')
  .reply(200, function () {        
    return fs.createReadStream('a.txt');
  });
```